# Apache NiFi EvaluateXQuery

Tags: apache-nifi

I am trying to use NiFi to break up an XML document into multiple flowfiles. The XML contains many  elements from a web service. I am trying to process each event separately. I think EvaluateXQuery is the appropriate processor but I can't figure out to add my XQuery if the destination is a flowfile rather than an attribute. I know I have to add a property /value pair in the processor config/properties page but I can't figure out what the property name should be. Does it matter?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you only need to extract one element, then yes, add a dynamic property with any name and set the destination to *flowfile-content*.

You can add multiple dynamic properties to the processor to extract elements into attributes on the outgoing flowfile. If you want to then replace the flowfile content with the attributes, you can use a processor like `ReplaceText` or `AttributesToJson` to combine multiple attributes into the flowfile content.

A couple things to remember:

- extracting multiple large elements to attributes is an anti-pattern, as this will hurt performance on the heap
- you might be better off splitting the XML file into chunks via `SplitXML` first in order to then extract a single element per chunk into the flowfile content (or an attribute)

Comment: Thanks! Your answer reassured me that I was on the right track. I was convinced that I was somehow messing up the property name. Instead, my XQuery was bad. A closer reading of the docs revealed that an XQuery processor with a  flowfile-content destination ignores the property name.